# android service, broadcast and activity

Tags: android, service, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

Current I have three classes: activity (A), broadcastReceiver (B) and service (C).

Assuming that A is binding to C and now, B get a new intent from system.

Can B bind to the C (exactly the same one) directly?

---

I find out that there is a peekService method in broadcastReceiver.

my question is can I bind the running service in broadcastReceiver?

Answer (score 1):

If you have registered your receiver dynamically with `Context.registerReceiver()` then you can bind to a `Service` from the `onReceive` method.

However, If you have declared your `BroadcastReceiver` in the manifest, then you should not bind to a Service from the `onReceive()` method. You can *start* a `Service` though - you just cannot bind to it because `bindService()` is asynchronous. More details about this in the [Android Dev Guide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#ReceiverLifecycle) and the [onReceive](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive%28android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent%29) documentation.

Comment: In my original answer, I had presented the wrong conditions. I edited the answer with the correct conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I find out that using peekService can bind the running service.

Such like

```
IBinder ib = peekService(context, new Intent(context,
                    xxxxService.class));
```

((xxxxService.class)ib).   do anything here...